# Pandas Dataframe Tail Not Working

Tags: python, pandas

The size of my pandas dataframe is 6844 and is named `all_data_frame`.

When I type `print(str(all_ssis_data.tail))` I get rows in the index range of 0-29 and 3633-3662.

Why doesn't it show me rows around the 6800 range?

Comment: I think you forget `()` like `print(all_ssis_data.tail())`

Comment: I get the last 5 rows but I'm still not getting rows around the 6800 range.

Comment: add () after the tail : `print(str(all_ssis_data.tail()))`

Comment: jezrael gives me the last 5 rows. Your version, ankit, gives me rows 0-29 and 3633-3662

Comment: Becuase it seems dulicated index values, try `print(all_ssis_data.reset_index(drop=True).tail())`

Comment: check what the number of rows in your dataframe is

Comment: 6884 is the size of the data frame

Comment: Jezrael your solution worked. If you post your solution as the answer, instead of a comment, I'll mark it as the answer in the future when my time restriction is up.

Comment: I spent 2 hours trying to figure this out . . . f*** me. lol lesson learned. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For default index values need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`, then add `()` to [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) function and omit converting to string:

```
print(all_ssis_data.reset_index(drop=True).tail())
```

Answer (score 0):

tail is a method of dataframe. You can do this:

print(str(all_ssis_data.tail()))

if you want to get page around 6800

you can add 50 as parameter

.tail(50) will show the last 50 rows